# Perf measure cache misses on AMD CPU

Tags: linux, perf, amd-processor

I'm using an AMD Ryzen 5 1600 CPU and I would like to use Perf to measure the cache misses of a program. When I run `perf stat -e cache-misses ./program` perf always reports 0 cache misses. Running `perf list` gives the following output:

```
  amd_iommu_0/cmd_processed/                         [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/cmd_processed_inv/                     [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/ign_rd_wr_mmio_1ff8h/                  [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/int_dte_hit/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/int_dte_mis/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/mem_dte_hit/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/mem_dte_mis/                           [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/mem_iommu_tlb_pde_hit/                 [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/mem_iommu_tlb_pde_mis/                 [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/mem_iommu_tlb_pte_hit/                 [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/mem_iommu_tlb_pte_mis/                 [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/mem_pass_excl/                         [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/mem_pass_pretrans/                     [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/mem_pass_untrans/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/mem_target_abort/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/mem_trans_total/                       [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/page_tbl_read_gst/                     [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/page_tbl_read_nst/                     [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/page_tbl_read_tot/                     [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/smi_blk/                               [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/smi_recv/                              [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/tlb_inv/                               [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/vapic_int_guest/                       [Kernel PMU event]
  amd_iommu_0/vapic_int_non_guest/                   [Kernel PMU event]
  branch-instructions OR cpu/branch-instructions/    [Kernel PMU event]
  branch-misses OR cpu/branch-misses/                [Kernel PMU event]
  cache-misses OR cpu/cache-misses/                  [Kernel PMU event]
  cache-references OR cpu/cache-references/          [Kernel PMU event]
  cpu-cycles OR cpu/cpu-cycles/                      [Kernel PMU event]
  instructions OR cpu/instructions/                  [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/aperf/                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/irperf/                                        [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/mperf/                                         [Kernel PMU event]
  msr/tsc/                                           [Kernel PMU event]
  stalled-cycles-backend OR cpu/stalled-cycles-backend/ [Kernel PMU event]
  stalled-cycles-frontend OR cpu/stalled-cycles-frontend/ [Kernel PMU event]

  rNNN                                               [Raw hardware event descriptor]
  cpu/t1=v1[,t2=v2,t3 ...]/modifier                  [Raw hardware event descriptor]
   (see 'man perf-list' on how to encode it)

  mem:<addr>[/len][:access]                          [Hardware breakpoint]
```

Running `sudo perf list` gives a lot more events than the ones above. I'm not sure why `cache-misses` isn't working because events like `branch-misses` are working. Maybe I have to use one of the `amd_iommu_0` events (`amd_iommu_0/mem_dte_mis/` looks promising but I'm not actually sure what it measures)? Is there any reference that explains what these events are?

Comment: If `sudo` shows more events, you can set `perf_event_paranoid` so you don't need to use perf all the time.  [What restriction is perf\_event\_paranoid == 1 actually putting on x86 perf?](//stackoverflow.com/q/51911368)

Answer (score 4):

The CPU flavor `AMD Ryzen 5 1600` is based on AMDs `Zen` microarchitecture family. A quick lookup of `Zen` tells me that the **CPUID** code associated with this microarchitecture is **17h**.

Note that, the event `cache-misses` is mapped to the generalized hardware event, **PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES** which is not readily available on all platforms.

Per the latest linux kernel [source](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.3.11/source/arch/x86/events/amd/core.c#L244) (which is 5.3.11) at the time of this writing, it can be seen that the event `cache-misses` is not directly supported for CPU family **17h** and above.

Note that, to understand most of the performance monitoring counter(**PMC**) events for AMD, you need to consult the below reference -

AMD BIOS and Kernel Developer Guide (I could not find it for CPU family 17h)

The other option is instead of passing names for events, you can pass the raw hexadecimal codes for the events, in the format `-e rXXXX` where `XXXX` is the code. Another answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46370111) describes how you can obtain this raw hexadecimal code for events like `cache-misses`.

You can also look at [this](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/drm/msm/commit/0e3b74e26280f2cf8753717a950b97d424da6046) commit to get further details as to how cache misses are being represented.

Comment: So are you saying that recording `cache-misses` is not supported for this processor? That seems strange given that it is such a general and common event.

Comment: I do not mean `cache-misses` is not supported. What I mean is `cache-misses` is not mapped to the hardware event that I specified and thereby not readily available. It is very likely aliased as another event name. The second option I suggested could lead you there.